# Comparing the predictive power of two non-independent ordinal independent variables

Tags: mathematical-statistics, chi-squared-test, predictive-models, ordinal-data, independence

I am looking to compare the predictive power of two ordinal independent variables (RA & 0.5RA+0.5RM) on success (please see image).

[image: Data structure]

These independent variables are not independent of each other.(Clearly 0.5RA+0.5RM will correlate with RA). How can I determine if one of these independent variables is significantly better at predicting success than the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response variable is ordinal with three levels, so try ordinal logistic regression, two models, one with each of the competing predictors, and compare them. You can for instance evaluate each of the models with cross-validation and see which is best.

Or fit one model with both predictors?

Comment: Yes, this makes a lot of sense. I will do it this way. Thank you for your help.